# Booting from USB or DVD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb

I am currently taking my first Linux course so I am very new to Linux.
I created a bootable USB followed the instructions to use on my MacBook. When I tried to boot up the UBS drive I was stuck at the Ubuntu purple screen. I was patient and let it sit there for almost an hour and noting. Then I decided to create the bootable DVD and nothing...not even the purple Ubuntu screen. 
Both times I choose to try Ubuntu and not to install it. What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

With USB, try [Unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/).

```
sudo apt-get install unetbootin
```

With DVD, follow [this](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-mac-osxhttp://).

Check again you iso (may corrupted, etc).

Comment: I added install instruction for unetbootin, that is important here but your second link does not even work! Please take the tour http://askubuntu.com/tour and read the help before posting http://askubuntu.com/help and make sure your links work.